# Why was a comment deleted as obsolete when part of it is still relevant?

Tags: discussion, comment

I noticed that my comment to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3706648) has disappeared. Why did it happen? If the comment was flagged as outdated and then removed, I believe this is wrong. The first part of the comment was about the confusion with integration limits, that has been corrected in the answer. The second part was about a substitution which is not justified and would give a wrong result for certain input values. That part is still very much relevant.

Comment: No one, save for a moderator, can see the deleted comment, or decide to restore it.  You should have flagged the answer on which you commented, for moderator attention, to inquire about the deleted comment, rather than posting to meta, where other users can not do anything about it.

Comment: If the second part of your Comment is still germane, you can repost it on that Answer.  This (rather than flagging for moderator attention) is probably the expeditious route.

Comment: You are taking, @hardmath, the OP's perception that (at least part of) their comment was relevant.  But the fact is, it was deleted by a mod.  Best to flag for mod attention to review the deletion, perhaps edit the comment  to exclude the obsolete, or otherwise.  Telling a commenter to  repost any part of a deleted comment is asking the commenter to risk further repercussions for doing so.

Comment: In any case, Maxim and @hardmath, this is a matter that mods are best equipped to handle.

Comment: @amWhy:  I'm proposing the second part of the original Comment can be reposted if it "is still germane."  The OP's "perception that (at least part of) their comment was relevant" deserves to be taken as of equal weight with yours, mine, or a moderator's.  Are there repercussions for posting an "obsolete" comment?  Let it be on my head then.

Comment: @hardmath:  They could have asked that when flagging for mod attention.  There is a pretty generous field in which one can express concerns to a mod, including a request to have "part of a comment restored".  As I stated earlier: this is a matter that only mods are best equipped to handle.  You cannot offer any arguments against that, else you'd have restored the comment by now, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was indeed flagged as no longer needed. Given that comment, edit, and reply to the comment were a week old, I validated the flag and deleted the comments. I did not check whether the complete comment was made obsolete by the edit, knowing one who flagged as generally reliable.

In principle, I'd support [hardmath](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3111/hardmath)'s suggestion:

> If the second part of your Comment is still germane, you can repost it on that Answer.

In this specific case, your comment has already been undeleted and the obsolete part removed by a colleague.

Comment: So, I take it, this matter could have and would have best been handled by flagging the post for moderator attention, explaining their issue about the deleted comment?  Thanks for confirming that indeed, only a mod could rectify the matter, and that the post here is off topic for that reason.

Comment: Specifically, you confirmed: "This should not be a meta discussion, as it is a call for moderator action. Instead, the problematic post or comment should be flagged for moderator attention."

Comment: Thanks for the edit @amWhy. (Old habits die hard. :-/) I'm not so sure if this is a call for moderator action or an inquiry about a moderator action, thus I'm in doubt whether it's off-topic or not.

Comment: Well, @DanielFischer, it is certainly a matter that could only be handled by a moderator, so flagging would have been preferable as opposed to wasting users' (who could not have changed anything anyway) time.

Comment: Unless you want every user who has a comment deleted  to contest it on meta.

Comment: @amWhy I agree that the issue would have been handled most *efficiently* via a flag. However, it can also be useful to at times to talk about certain things in more detail. For instance other users can learn from this thread that "no longer needed" is often validated quite rapidly especially if there is a comment that says "it is fixed." To avoid this, one would basically need to add another comment that a part is still relevant, or preemptively .repost the part and delete the other one.

Comment: touche, @quid! Understood.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up, and thanks to the people who offered suggestions. I must say I'm not quite comfortable with anyone *invisibly* editing what I wrote (I realize the editing wasn't done by you). But I suppose in this case it reduces the chance that the comment may be removed again.